# ReactGridLayout: ReactGridLayout.children[0].x must be a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-grid-layout

im setting up list add for grid that i removed and then store it to the list data, its works before but when im trying to add right now but got this error.
ReactGridLayout: ReactGridLayout.children[0].x must be a number!

```
 listAdd(x){

        let addItems = [...this.state.addItems];
        let items = [...this.state.items];

        items.push(x)
        addItems.splice(addItems.indexOf(x),1)
        console.log(items, 'uitems');
        console.log(addItems, 'items')
        this.setState({
            items: items,
            addItems: addItems
        })
    }
```

```
getInput(key){
        //let ls = {};
        let value = localStorage.getItem("layoutsJR") || {};
        //ls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("layoutsJR")) || {};
        try{
            //parse localstorage string dan set state
            value = JSON.parse(value)
            this.setState({
            [key]: value
            })
        }catch(e){
            //handle empty string
            this.setState({
            [key]: value
            })
        }
        //console.log(value[key], "get inputan move")
        return value[key]


        // return ls[key];
    }

    updateInput(key, value){
        this.setState({
            [key] : value
        })

        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify({[key]: value}))
    }
```

```
onRemoveItem(i){

        let addItems = [...this.state.addItems];
        let items = [...this.state.items];
        addItems.push(items[i]);
        items.splice(i, 1);
        this.setState({
            addItems : addItems,
            items :items
        })
    }
```

```
 class AddRemoveLayout extends React.Component{
    // static get defaultProps() {
    //     return {
    //     className: "layout",
    //     cols: {lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2},
    //     rowHeight: 100,
    //     onLayoutChange: function(){}
    //     }
    // };

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            itemsDefault :[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(function(i){
                return{
                    i: i.toString(),
                    x: i*2,
                    y: 2,
                    w: 3,
                    h: 3
                };
            }),
            items: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(function(i){
                return{
                    i: i.toString(),
                    x: i*2,
                    y: 2,
                    w: 3,
                    h: 3
                };
            }),
            addItems:[],
            fullScreen: true,
            tempSisa: null,
            addItemsSisa: [],
            quantity:"",
            showWidget: false,
            isChecked: true,
            product: '',
            layouts: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.getInput("layoutsJR")|| []))

        };
```

```
render(){
        let items = this.state.items;
        let addItems = this.state.addItems;

        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.fullScreen ? 
                    <div class="buttonMenu">


                <Dropdown class="dropdownList">
                    <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
                        List Add
                    </Dropdown.Toggle>

                    <Dropdown.Menu>
                      {addItems.map((index) =>{
                          return <Dropdown.Item key={index} onClick={this.listAdd.bind(this, index)}>{index.i}</Dropdown.Item>
                      })}
                    </Dropdown.Menu>
                </Dropdown></div> : <div></div>}

                <ResponsiveReactGridLayout

                    className="layout"
                    cols={{lg: 12, md:10, sm:6, xs:4, xxs:2}}
                    rowHeight={30}
                    layouts={this.state.layouts} 
                    onLayoutChange={(layout, layouts)=>this.onLayoutChange(layout, layouts)} 
                    onBreakpointChange={this.onBreakpointChange} 

                >{_.map(this.state.items, (el, index) => {return this.createElement(el, index)})
                /*this.state.items.map((el, index) => {
                    return this.createElement(el, index)
                })*/
                }
                </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

its works before that i adding table in my grid layout but then i got this error ReactGridLayout: ReactGridLayout.children[0].x must be a number!

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your layout. Can you post them up?

Comment: okay i will edit my  post first

Comment: is that to display my grid layout right?

Comment: can i have your email or something? coz my layout its too large @TreeNguyen

Comment: You can post a small copy of it. Or how you create your layout

Comment: my layouts just get the data from localStorage

Comment: i already update it the layouts i tried to save it to localstorage and then, i put the table inside the grid

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you're addressing an issue related to passing data within an HTML element in a React application using the `react-grid-layout` library. Here's a summary of your issue and the resolution:

**Issue**:
You encountered a problem where you were passing a plain JavaScript object as a child element to `ResponsiveReactGridLayout` instead of using an HTML element with the `data-grid` attribute.

**Resolution**:
To resolve this issue, you should pass the object as an attribute (specifically, the `data-grid` attribute) to the first element inside the `ResponsiveReactGridLayout` component.

Here's the corrected code:

```
<ResponsiveReactGridLayout layout={layout}>
  {layout.map((item) => (
    <div key={item.i} data-grid={item} className="block">
      {item.i}
    </div>
  ))}
</ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
```

In the corrected code, each `div` element has the `data-grid` attribute set to the corresponding `item` from your layout array, ensuring that the data is correctly associated with the HTML element.

For more details and to see the resolved code, you can refer to the provided links:

- [Error Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-margulis-kmxgz7?file=/src/App.js)
- [Resolved Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/fixed-react-grid-layout-issue-n95r7f?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Keep in mind that AI-generated or assisted answers are [not allowed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1), even if they are part of another coding tool like the one you link to (or even Copilot Chat).